Connecting to azure iot hub from client side react app within an iOS wrapper
We are attempting to connect a vite react web app to an azure iot hub.
We'd like to use a .pem, and .key file to register the device with gobal.azure-devices-provisioning.net as shown in their github repo example
https://github.com/Azure-Samples/azure-iot-samples-node/blob/5e06db800818cf5a4d0dcfeea19c749f62a3c2d7/provisioning/Samples/device/register_x509.js#L52
but the "azure-iot-provisioning-device-http", "azure-iot-security-x509", and"azure-iot-provisioning-device" rely on node packages that are not included in the device version, so having the web app do the registration/communication appears to be off the table.
Since the app is going to be running in a wrapper on a tablet we then tried both iOS and android SDKs and found similar missing packages in their versions. they don't seem to come with the capability to use the ProvisioningDeviceClient. I suspect that all of the microsoft sdk stuff is only intended for node.js or java servers, but they I didn't notice them specifying that anywhere in their docs
So with that set up, are we trying to do something super rare and weird? did I miss some important setup step? Any guidance, or tutorials for this would be amazing. Thank you all in advance.
in the react app we imported
    "azure-iot-device": "^1.18.3",
    "azure-iot-device-mqtt": "^1.16.3",
    "azure-iot-provisioning-device": "^1.9.1",
    "azure-iot-provisioning-device-mqtt": "^1.8.1",
    "azure-iot-security-x509": "^1.8.2",

but ran into those packages needing access to missing node.js packages like net and others to function. when i attempted the same thing in a simple node.js server app there was no problem and i was able to register with the server and connect.
in the iOS app we pod installed
  pod 'AzureIoTUtility', '=1.5.0'
  pod 'AzureIoTuMqtt', '=1.5.0'
  pod 'AzureIoTuAmqp', '=1.5.0'
  pod 'AzureIoTHubClient', '=1.5.0'

I went crawling around in their c code for a day and didn't find anything for registering the device
in the android app we added to the gradle.build
    implementation("com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client:1.30.1")
    implementation("com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-service-client:1.30.1")
    implementation("com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot:iot-device-client-provisioning:1.30.1")

but the com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.device package doesn't exist so we can't get to the com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot.provisioning.device.ProvisioningDeviceClient class

you're going to need a backend

Present there is only sdk support for node and node API.  Provisioning classes issue with react+vite.

One best way is to use node api as backend and react +vite as front end where an Express server manages device registration using Azure IoT provisioning, while a React frontend allows users to trigger the registration process.
The below express backend code sets up an server to handle device registration requests using Azure IoT Provisioning Service.

It loads device certificates, configures the IoT Provisioning client, and exposes an endpoint /register for device registration

const express = require('express');
const fs = require('fs');
const Transport = require('azure-iot-provisioning-device-http').Http;
const X509Security = require('azure-iot-security-x509').X509Security;
const ProvisioningDeviceClient = require('azure-iot-provisioning-device').ProvisioningDeviceClient;
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();

// Middleware to parse JSON bodies
app.use(express.json());

// Enable CORS
app.use(cors());

// Configuration
const provisioningHost = process.env.PROVISIONING_HOST;
const idScope =  process.env.PROVISIONING_IDSCOPE;
const registrationId = process.env.REGISTRATION_ID;

// Check if required environment variables are set
if (!idScope || !registrationId) {
  console.error('Please set ID_SCOPE and REGISTRATION_ID environment variables.');
  process.exit(-1);
}

// Device certificate and key paths
const deviceCertPath = 'C://device-cert.pem';
const deviceKeyPath = 'C://unencrypted-device-key.pem';

// Load device certificate and key
const deviceCert = {
  cert: fs.readFileSync(deviceCertPath).toString(),
  key: fs.readFileSync(deviceKeyPath).toString()
};

// Device provisioning client setup
const transport = new Transport();
const securityClient = new X509Security(registrationId, deviceCert);
const deviceClient = ProvisioningDeviceClient.create(provisioningHost, idScope, transport, securityClient);

// Device registration endpoint
app.post('/register', (req, res) => {
  // Register the device
  deviceClient.register((err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Error registering device:', err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Device registration failed' });
    } else {
      console.log('Device registration succeeded');
      return res.status(200).json(result);
    }
  });
});

// Start the server
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});






The below react frontend provides a user interface for initiating device registration. When the user clicks the Register Device button, a POST request is sent to the backend’s /register endpoint.
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const registerDevice = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/register', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      });

      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Error: ${res.status} ${res.statusText}`);
      }

      const data = await res.json();
      setResponse(data);
      setError(null);
    } catch (err) {
      setResponse(null);
      setError(err.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Device Registration</h1>
      <button onClick={registerDevice}>Register Device</button>
      {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>Error: {error}</p>}
      {response && (
        <pre>
          {JSON.stringify(response, null, 2)}
        </pre>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;






To understand the details about the issue with React or React + Vite using Azure IoT Hub provisioning classes, please follow this issue.

Refer to this links for how to create React Native Wrappers for Native SDKs.

Refer to this link to provision an X.509 certificate simulated device with c code .

Refer  this link  to provision an X.509 certificate simulated device with java


<dependencies>
        <!-- Azure IoT Device SDK -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot</groupId>
            <artifactId>iot-device-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Azure IoT Provisioning Device Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure.sdk.iot</groupId>
            <artifactId>provisioning-device-client</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        .
        .
        .
  <dependencies>


Once you get that registration information from the server are you able to use that to build a connection string and instantiate a client that can talk back and forth with the iot server from the vite side, or would you need to set those up as additional post endpoints?  var connectionString = 'HostName=' + result.assignedHub + ';DeviceId=' + result.deviceId + ';x509=true';                     var hubClient = Client.fromConnectionString(connectionString, iotHubTransport);

you need set those up as additional post to get Primary Thumbprint,Secondary Thumbprint.

of x509 azure Iot device
